# Animating a UITabBar's shadowImage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I want to fade the shadow image of a UITabBar (iOS7) from the default shadow to a custom image. I don't have access to the default shadow but if necessary can access the UITabBar's layer.

Comment: your idea sounds good. can you please make me more clear on your point.

Comment: `tabBar.shadowImage` is initially nil (the default shadow) and I later set it to a custom UIImage. I would like to animate that transition with a crossfade between the default and custom images.